# Is it possible to put beamer blocks in tikz nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, block

I would like to use tikz to position beamer blocks in the frame. Here is my attempt, but it does not compile:

```
\documentclass[beamer]{beamerswitch}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}\frametitle{My title}
    \thispagestyle{empty} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \node[anchor=north] at ($(current page.north)+(0,-0.1\textheight)$) {
        \begin{block}{Test block}
        \end{block}
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here is the console error :

```
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.16   \end{frame}

?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is like a multiline node. You have some options to resolve it, here I propose two.

- Determine the width of the node, thus determine the width of `block`, by `text width`:

  ```latex
  \documentclass[beamer]{beamerswitch}
  \usetheme{metropolis}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc}
  \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
  \usepackage{lipsum}
  \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}\frametitle{My title}
      \thispagestyle{empty} 
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[anchor=north,text width=.8\textwidth] 
          at ($(current page.north)+(0,-0.1\textheight)$) {
            \begin{block}{This is a block}
              \lipsum[2]
            \end{block}
          };
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
  \end{document}
  ```

  [image]
- Use `minipage`

  ```latex
  \documentclass[beamer]{beamerswitch}
  \usetheme{metropolis}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc}
  \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
  \usepackage{lipsum}
  \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}\frametitle{My title}
      \thispagestyle{empty} 
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[anchor=north] at ($(current page.north)+(0,-0.1\textheight)$) {
          \begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{This is a block}
              \lipsum[2]
            \end{block}
          \end{minipage}
        };
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
  \end{document}
  ```

  (same output as above)

Comment: You have saved my day ! What are the pros and cons to use a minipage please? Besides, what did I miss?

Comment: @lalebarde Both proposals are to make the node width fixed. In your code, the node width is not fixed, so Ti*k*Z doesn't know e.g. where to break lines in the node, etc. To explain further I have to dig into the internal of `beamer`, but I think it is not necessary

Comment: Thank you, thank you, *thank you*!!! This is exactly what I needed